# How to send a trigger to Puppet?

Tags: puppet

Is there anyway to send a trigger to Puppet to perform a series to tasks ?

The application is served by Apache httpd. Every once in a while developers make changes to the product which in turn requires us to restart Apache. However, I cannot figure out how to send a request to Puppet which in turn will restart Apache.

Basically, this is more of a asynchronous request compared to a "serial" or synchronous flow of Puppet run that executes every 30 minutes.

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: How is your product deployed? Is this a development/test/prod/etc. environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `puppet` is not a task manager.  `puppet` is a state manager.

- It does not start or restart `httpd`; rather, it ensures that `httpd` is running.
- It does not upload files, it verifies that files are installed and up-to-date.

The distinction is important.

That said ...

Is `puppet` also managing the changes being made by the developers?

If so, then you should be able to create a puppet rule

```
exec { httpdrestart :
    command => "/sbin/service httpd restart",
    refreshonly => true,
}
```

and then attach to whatever `puppet` rule is managing your developers' changes

```
file { '/var/www/html/mywebproject.html':
  ensure => present,
  source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/mywebproject.html',
  notify => Exec["httpdrestart"]
}
```

that after this file is installed/updated/changed, `httpd` needs to be restarted.

If you just expect `puppet` to restart httpd simple because you asked it to, then you either need to use a program like `ansible` which is more of an actual task manager, or use some kind of `inotify` thing to see that a certain file has been changed, so `httpd` must be restarted.

(caveat -- but I know nothing about `inotify` beyond the name.)

Comment: Restarting httpd is the easy part ; the trigger part is the one I needed help with. I have had others suggest "ansible" in the past too ; I need to take a look at it. I will also check inotify. Since your suggestion is to restart httpd after a file is installed/updated/changed, is there a way to upload a file using Puppet ?

Comment: edited my answer to address your follow-up question.

Comment: I agree with @hymie, Puppet seems to be the wrong tool for the OP's problem. [Bolt](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/bolt.html) however might satisfy the requirements. It's designed to be used along with Puppet for as-needed one-time jobs like restarting services or shutting them down as part of an emergency response in case of an attack. It connects to the target machines using SSH to execute the commands in a similar way Ansible does.